# Example of a homeomorphism of the extended complex plane that is not circle-preserving

Tags: hyperbolic-geometry

Can you give me an example of a homeomorphism of the extended complex plane that is not circle-preserving?

Comment: Homeomorphism of what?

Comment: Wow I'm so sorry. I have forgotten to write that.

Comment: What do you mean by "cycle preserving"? Is a hyperbolic geodesic line a cycle? Is it "complex plane" or the "upper half plane"?

Comment: It is circle-preserving. It maps circles into circles. The circles of the extended complex plane are in two form: Either it is a Euclidean circle in the complex plane or it is a Euclidean line in the complex plane combined with the point at infinity.

Comment: The extended complex plane is the union of the complex plane joined with the point at infinity.

Comment: So you are not talking about hyperbolic plane.

Comment: I know only one model of the hyperbolic plane that is the upper-half plane of the complex plane.

Comment: There are several other models (the two disc models, for example).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The linear map given by the matrix $$\left(\begin{array}{cc}2 & 1\\ 1 & 1\end{array}\right)$$ is a homeomorphism which does not preserve circles.

Comment: Its determinant is nonzero so that makes it a Möbius transformation and Möbius transformations preserve circles. Do I miss something?

Comment: Moebius transformation corresponding to this matrix would be $\frac {2z+1}{z+1}$. My answer is about the linear map $a+bi\to 2a+b+(a+b)i$

Comment: This linear map takes circles to ellipses.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I'm sorry that I can not upvote your answer because I'm new here.

Comment: Probably you can still accept it.